# Eventbrite API sort_by date doesn't work?

Tags: eventbrite

I am trying to get a list of events from the Eventbrite API, and sort them by date.

However I seem to get an event list that is not ordered by date.

Here is an example:

```
$ curl "https://www.eventbrite.com/json/event_search?app_key=MY_API_KEY&country=GB&sort_by=date" | jsonlint | grep start_date
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 68722    0 68722    0     0  42483      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:-- 61413
        "start_date": "2013-03-23 09:00:00",
        "start_date": "2013-03-23 09:00:00",
        "start_date": "2013-03-31 13:00:00",
              "start_date": "2013-01-18 01:45:00",
        "start_date": "2013-03-28 09:00:00",
              "start_date": "2013-02-01 05:55:00",
              "start_date": "2013-02-01 05:55:00",
              "start_date": "2013-02-01 05:55:00",
        "start_date": "2013-03-23 10:00:00",
              "start_date": "2013-01-01 00:00:00",
              "start_date": "2012-12-12 00:00:00",
        "start_date": "2013-04-09 19:00:00",
        "start_date": "2013-04-13 09:00:00",
        "start_date": "2013-04-17 18:15:00",
        "start_date": "2013-04-17 19:00:00",
        "start_date": "2013-04-17 19:00:00",
```

(The non-indented start_times are those for events)

I know it is accepting the sort_by=date parameter as it is returned in the results summary:

```
{
  "summary": {
    "total_items": 14911,
    "first_event": 4673700163,
    "last_event": 5844441883,
    "filters": {
      "country": "GB",
      "sort_by": "date"
    },
    "num_showing": 10
  }
},
```

I've assumed the date it sorts by is the start_date, but manually inspecting the other dates (end_date, created, modified) it doesn't seem to be sorting by that either.

Is this a bug in the API or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

afaik, Eventbrite allows you to sort by location **OR** by date, but not both.

It's possible that since you selected a country / region (GB), the date sorting is not being applied.

Comment: But I have '&sort_by=date' in my request.

Comment: but you also have country=GB, which is a location query, which blocks the date sort from working correctly :(